# Kendo DataBound e.model object VS Edit e.model object

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo DataBound event to print the model from the row triggering the event, the problem I'm facing is the model is undefined when using DataBound different from using Edit event.

```
.Events(e => { e.DataBound(@<text>function(e) { alert(e.model); }</text>) })
```

The problem is that apparently e.DataBound is not handling the e argument as the Edit, Cancel, and the rest of events.

When trying with `e.Edit(@<text>function(e) { alert(e.model); }</text>)` the e.model object is loaded with the properties and values.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Event args aren't the same for all kinds of events, as they has different purposes. In your case, edit event is meant to handle a specific entry data, hence the `model` property. The dataBound event runs whenever any data is bound to the widget, so it can be more than one specific entry. Anyways, you always has the option to access data as `this.dataSource.data()` inside dataBound event scope.

Comment: To add to the answer above, dataBound is not necessarily fired when one item changes, it can be fired once when all the rows have loaded, for example. Depending on what you're trying to do, you may want to use the dataSource's [change](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/change) event.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown @GaloisGirl - What I'm trying to achieve is to bound a click event something like `events.DataBound(@<text>function(e) {  $('.k-grid-custom1').bind("click", function(){ alert(e.model) }); ; }</text>);` where the .k-grid-custom1 belongs to a cell on each row of my grid, so every time you click over this cell the alert will display the model from the clicked row. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look at [this Kendo example](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command) where they use `var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));` to get the data for the clicked row.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using jQuery only:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
      $('#grid').kendoGrid({
         dataSource: {
           data: [{ A: 1, B: 2 }, { A: 3, B: 4 }]
         },
      });
      
      let grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
      
      $("#grid").on('click', 'tbody td', function(e) {
        let $td = $(e.target),
            dataItem = grid.dataItem($td.parent()),
            cellContent = dataItem[$td.data('field')];
        
        console.log($td, dataItem, cellContent);
      });
    });
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ugUlEyIJ)

---

Or by using the grid's [`change`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/change) event. But in order to use that event you need to set your grid [`selectable`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/selectable) to `true`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
      $('#grid').kendoGrid({
         dataSource: {
           data: [{ A: 1, B: 2 }, { A: 3, B: 4 }]
         },
         selectable: true,
         change: function() {
           let dataItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
           
           console.log(dataItem);
         }
      });
    });
  </script>  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ugUlEyIJ/2)